# How do I Convert Flutter slider double value to int

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-test

I'm writing code for BMI calculator, and I'm using the slider for height and it returns a double type a long one. I tried `_startHeight.toInt()` but in vain. And Is there any way to show label without using division.

Here is my slider code.

```
               Slider(
                  value: _startHeight,
                  min: 1,
                  max: 100,
                  onChanged: (newHeight) {
                    setState(() {
                      _startHeight = newHeight;
                      _startHeight.toInt();
                      print(_startHeight);
                    });
                  },
                ),
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if you want `_startHeight` to be an `int` then I assumed you defined it to be an `int` in the first place.

you are trying to assign a `double` to an `int`, and then to change this `double` to `int`. you need to do it the other way around:

```
onChanged: (double newHeight) {
  setState(() {
    _startHeight = newHeight.toInt();
    print(_startHeight);
  });
}
```

If your ultimate goal is to display the value in a String without decimal, then you can use `toStringAsFixed`:

`_startHeight.toStringAsFixed(0);`

Comment: it will not work  `_startHeight` is double,  `toInt()` will convert the newHeight (double) to int and A value of type `int` can't be assigned to a variable of type `double`.

Comment: in this case you need to define `_startHeight` to be an `int`. Then the piece of code I provided in my answer should work :)

Comment: the `value` property in slider accepts `double` type. see the docs https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Slider-class.html

Comment: why do you want to change it to an `int` then ?

Comment: If this is only for display purposes, then you can use `toStringAsFixed `. I edited my answer :)

Comment: this is what I'm getting https://i.imgur.com/GPCmPBb.jpg I just want it to be `int` type to get the whole value as a result.

Comment: Please have a look at my edited answer. It is bad practice to change your `double` to an `int`. Instead, as you only want to display the value of `_startHeight` in a specific way, use the `toStringAsFixed` method showed in my answer :)

Comment: Thanks a lot _startHeight.toStringAsFixed(0); works well.